# Vue.js on click method , not working on laravel project

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, webpack

As the code below , the vue.js component works correctly , but the on-click method does not work at all and there is no cached errors . it seems that the function does not get called . When webpack is disabled , the code works correctly.
The HTML code :

```
<div class="row my-4">
    <div class="col-8">
        <h5>{{price}} $$</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <button type="button" v-on:click="inquiry" class="btn btn-yui mx-auto btn-block">price</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Vue.js section

```
methods: {
    inquiry: function(){      
        axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/api/brand/panel/get/price/plan`,this.form,{
          headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'}
        })
        .then(response => {
          this.price = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. What you posted should work just fine, which means you're not showing the source of your bug. Therefore, your question is not answerable.

Comment: Probably you missed `}` to end methods.  `methods:{ inquiry: function(){ /*your axios*/ } },`

Answer (score 0):

You use
`<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>`

or no need to mix or something under app.blade.php files.This line default call layouts/app.blade.php

it's work for me.
Thank you.